# PHP make image based on percentage instead of resoulution

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I am making a PHP web application which enables users to create posters.

There are some specific fields that they can change and of course there are some parts of the poster that cannot be changed.

The users will be able to get the poster in multiple sizes so as an example I want to know how I can make a line like this:

```
imageline( $my_img, 30,
      200, 80, 200, $line_colour );
```

Scale so if a user wants the image double as large it will be changed to:

```
imageline( $my_img, 60,
      400, 160, 400, $line_colour );
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variables instead of hardcoded values.

```
[html form]
<select name="resize">
    <option value="1">Normal</option>
    <option value="2">Double size</option>
    <option value="3">Triple size</option>
</select>

[php]
$resize = !empty($_POST['resize']) ? intval($_POST['resize']) : 1;

$x1 = 30 * $resize;
$x2 = 80 * $resize;
$y1 = 200 * $resize;
$y2 = 200 * $resize;

imageline($my_img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $line_colour);
```

---

Or if you wish to avoid variables, you can write expressions directly to function call:

```
imageline($my_img, 30 * $resize, 80 * $resize, 200 * $resize, 200 * $resize, $line_colour);
```

or even move `$resize` expression to it's value places.

Comment: You must check that input is one of the allowed:
``$resize = in_array($_POST['resize'], array(1,2,3))? (int)$_POST['resize']: 1;`` Here, POST value could be 0xffffffff or negative and raise errors.

Comment: @Xenos OP is not asking how to validate user input nor it's showing from where parameters are coming from. Yes, you have to validate input in few ways.

Comment: The problem is that I have 6 lines and that would require 24 variables which seems kinda wild.

Comment: @Niclassg you can write expressions directly to function call. But that will be less readable in my opinion.